# GatherBy based on condition imposed on index variable

Tags: list-manipulation, programming, gathering

Excuse me. This might be user specific question but I need your help. I have an indexed data, where positive integers are used for indexing data. I am trying to group data putting condition on index variable so that I can analyze group-wise data. But I don't know. Please guide me. Here is an example:

```
testdat = {{1, a11, b11}, {1, a12, b12}, {2, a21, b21}, {3, a31, 
   b31}, {4, a41, b41}, {2, a22, b22}, {3, a32, b32}, {3, a33, 
   b33}, {4, a42, b42}, {5, a51, b51}, {6, a61, b61}, {6, a62, 
   b62}, {5, a52, b52}, {5, a53, b53}, {5, b54, b54}};
```

If I do the following

```
GatherBy[testdat, First]
```

it groups data using first column as index. However, I want to group data in which rows indexed 1 and 2 should be one group, rows indexed 3,4 and 5 should be another group and row indexed 6 should be another group. Here is how the result should look like:

> ```
> {{{1, a11, b11}, {1, a12, b12}, {2, a21, b21}, {2, a22, b22}}, {{3, 
>    a31, b31}, {3, a32, b32}, {3, a33, b33}, {4, a41, b41}, {4, a42, 
>    b42}, {5, a51, b51}, {5, a52, b52}, {5, a53, b53}, {5, b54, 
>    b54}}, {{6, a61, b61}, {6, a62, b62}}}
> ```

Another way to group the data would be to put rows indexed 1,2 and 3 into one group and rows indexed 4,5 and 6 into another group like in the following result:

> ```
> {{{1, a11, b11}, {1, a12, b12}, {2, a21, b21}, {2, a22, b22}, {3, a31,
>     b31}, {3, a32, b32}, {3, a33, b33}}, {{4, a41, b41}, {4, a42, 
>    b42}, {5, a51, b51}, {5, a52, b52}, {5, a53, b53}, {5, b54, 
>    b54}, {6, a61, b61}, {6, a62, b62}}};
> ```

This is just the theory. I need code to perform this job. I expect to hearing form Great guys form this community. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can `MapIndexed` over a list of group lists to create an indexing function `g`, then compose this with the test function `fn`:

```
gatherInto1[dat_, fn_, groups__List] :=
  Module[{g},
    MapIndexed[(g[#] = #2[[1]]) &, {groups}, {2}];
    GatherBy[dat, g @ fn @ # &]
  ]
```

Example:

```
gatherInto1[testdat, First, {1, 2}, {3, 4, 5}, {6}]
```

> ```
> {
>  {{1, a11, b11}, {1, a12, b12}, {2, a21, b21}, {2, a22, b22}},
>  {{3, a31, b31}, {4, a41, b41}, {3, a32, b32}, {3, a33, b33}, {4, a42, b42},
>    {5, a51, b51}, {5, a52, b52}, {5, a53, b53}, {5, b54, b54}},
>  {{6, a61, b61}, {6, a62, b62}}
> }
> ```

In *Mathematica 10* we can use [`GroupBy`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GroupBy.html) and [`Lookup`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Lookup.html).  (Fred Simons referenced this but did not provide a complete implementation.)

```
gatherInto2[dat_, fn_, groups__List] :=
  With[{asc = GroupBy[dat, fn]},
    Join @@ Lookup[asc, #, {}] & /@ {groups}
  ]
```

Each function has its place.

- `gatherInto1` works with patterns whereas `gatherInto2` does not.
- `gatherInto2` can be quite a bit faster than `gatherInto1`.

Timings:

```
big = RandomInteger[{1, 6}, {500000, 3}];

gatherInto1[big, First, {1, 2}, {3, 4, 5}, {6}] // AbsoluteTiming // First
gatherInto2[big, First, {1, 2}, {3, 4, 5}, {6}] // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> ```
> 0.524
>
> 0.029
> ```

Comment: As always, thank you so much, Mr. Wizard.

Answer (score 2):

```
Cases[testdat, {Alternatives[##], __}] & @@@ {{1, 2}, {3, 4, 5}, {6}}
```

Update:

based on your comment you can do it using two methods:
prepare your index before

```
index=Range[1,6,2]
```

and then

```
Cases[testdat, {Alternatives[##], __}] & @@@ {index}
```

you can also do it like this:

```
Flatten[Table[Cases[testdat, {i, __}], {i, 1, 6, 2}], 1]
```

Comment: @ Algohi, thank you for your answer. What if I have a large data and index is too big to navigate. In fact, I have over 2M  obs.

Comment: if you have too big data then cases is your choose because it is fast. i don't get what you mean be index is too big to navigate? as long as you have the criteria to group the rows then you can use this method.

Comment: In your code, you have {{1, 2}, {3, 4, 5}, {6}} as criterion. Can we specify criteria as function than list? Like index is between two numbers: i<=index<=i+1, {i, 1, 6, 2}. Something like this.

Comment: @ Algohi, thanks for your update. I think, this might serve my need. I am working on it thought on my real data set.

Comment: you mean newindex=Partition[oldindex, 3]? use index instead of {index} in my code. like this: Cases[testdat, {Alternatives[##], __}] & @@@newindex

Comment: I did try this but I get all blanks. Let me work more on it and get back to you.

Comment: does this resemble your problem? Cases[RandomInteger[20, {200, 3}], {Alternatives[##], __}] & @@@ 
 Partition[Range[20], 3]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19418/discussion-between-rka-and-algohi).

Comment: This code is less than optimal because the input list will be scanned once for each group.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I Agree. The input list is scanned once for  each group.

Comment: @Algohi It's not really bad however with the example given (only three groups) so +1 for a clean method nevertheless.

Comment: By the way this can be written `Cases[testdat, {# | ##2, __}] & @@@ {{1, 2}, {3, 4, 5}, {6}}` if you like that sort of weirdness. :^)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard thanks for the up voting and for the new thinks I learned about ## :-), ^_ _

Answer (score 2):

One of the ways is the following:

```
GatherBy[testdat, Position[{{1, 2}, {3, 4, 5}, 6}, #[[1]]][[1]] &]

(* {{{1, a11, b11}, {1, a12, b12}}, {{2, a21, b21}, {2, a22, b22}}, {{3, a31, b31}, {3, a32, b32}, {3, a33, b33}}, {{4, a41, b41}, {4, a42, b42}}, {{5, a51, b51}, {5, a52, b52}, {5, a53, b53}, {5, b54, b54}}, {{6, a61, b61}, {6, a62, b62}}}  *)
```

For your second gathering, you can replace the first argument of Position with {{1,2,3}, {4,5,6}}.

It might be that the following is not exactly what you are looking for, but it shows something of the flexability of working with Associations. Here I construct the association:

```
asc=Association[ (First[#]->Rest[#])& /@ testdat]

(* <|1->{a12,b12},2->{a22,b22},3->{a33,b33},4->{a42,b42},5->{b54,b54},6->{a62,b62}|> *)
```

And here are the values with keys 1,2,3:

```
Lookup[asc,Key /@ {1,2,3}]

(*  {{a12,b12},{a22,b22},{a33,b33}} *)
```

Comment: @ Fred, thank you for your answer. What if I have a large data and index is too big to navigate. In fact, I have over 2m  rows.

Comment: @rka I have no experience at all with large data sets. But I understood that the function Lookup with Associations is very fast, and independent where you want to look in your data (beginning or end). I also understood that Associations are "memory hungry". My feeling is that if your data set fits in the memory of Mathematica as an Association, you will be better of with Lookup, of course depending of what you want to do. So I edited my answer showing how you could transform your testdat to an Association and how you could use LookUp. You might also look at the function GroupBy.

Comment: @ Fred, thank you fro your suggestion. I will work on your function and suggestion. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

```
group = (Switch[#, 
                1 | 2 | 3, 1,
                _,         2
         ] &);


GatherBy[testdat, group[ #[[1]] ] & ]
```

> ```
> {
>    {{1, a11, b11}, {1, a12, b12}, {2, a21, b21}, {3, a31, b31}, {2, a22, b22},
>     {3, a32, b32}, {3, a33, b33}}, 
>    {{4, a41, b41}, {4, a42, b42}, {5, a51, b51}, {6, a61, b61}, {6, a62, b62}, 
>     {5, a52, b52}, {5, a53, b53}, {5, b54, b54}}
> }
> ```

and for oryginal request:

```
group = (Switch[#, 
                6,     1,
                1 | 2, 2, 
                _,     3] &);
```

> ```
> {
>     {{1, a11, b11}, {1, a12, b12}, {2, a21, b21}, {2, a22, b22}}, 
>     {{3, a31, b31}, {4, a41, b41}, {3, a32, b32}, {3, a33, b33}, 
>      {4, a42, b42}, {5, a51, b51}, {5, a52, b52}, {5, a53, b53}, {5, b54, b54}},
>     {{6, a61, b61}, {6, a62, b62}}
>  }
> ```

Comment: @ Kuba, thank you for your time to answer this question.

Comment: @rka no problem, is it useful? :)

Comment: @ I am trying to apply your code to my need but failing. Whether you could help me. I have data indexed form 40 to 1057. That is oldindex=Range[40,1057]. I have constructed newindex like newindex=Partition[oldindexindex, 3]; Now I want to group data according to new index. Any help

Comment: In general, if you can find a function  f that is constant on each of your groups of indices, then you can use that function in GatherBy with argument #[[1]]. In this special case GatherBy[dataset, Floor[(#[[1]] - 1)/3] &] will work.

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun:

```
Join @@@ ({{1, 2}, {3, 4, 5}, {6}} /.Last@Reap[Sow[{##}, #1] & @@@ testdat, _, Rule])
```

yields:

```
{{{1, a11, b11}, {1, a12, b12}, {2, a21, b21}, {2, a22, b22}}, {{3, 
   a31, b31}, {3, a32, b32}, {3, a33, b33}, {4, a41, b41}, {4, a42, 
   b42}, {5, a51, b51}, {5, a52, b52}, {5, a53, b53}, {5, b54, 
   b54}}, {{6, a61, b61}, {6, a62, b62}}}
```

Comment: thanks for taking time to answer my question.